# Как экранировать знаки / в переменной

Tags: bash

Есть строка в переменной, например "123/456/789". Нужно экранировать все знаки /, чтобы перед каждым слешем был обратный слеш

Comment: После каждого слеша ставьте `*`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Например sed:

```
NEW_VAR=$(sed 's,/,\\/,g' <<< $OLD_VAR)
```

или просто на баше

```
NEW_VAR=${OLD_VAR//\//\\/}
```

Answer (score 4):

Смотря для каких целей в дальнейшем требуется выполнение:

```
a="123/456/789"
b=${a////\\/}
```

---

```
a - имя переменной  
// - разделитель  
/  - заменяемый символ/набор (что)  
/  - разделитель  
\\/  - набор/символ замены (на что)
```

`echo $b`
`123\/456\/789`

Если переменная будет проходить несколько этапов обработки, то количество символов экранирования следует увеличить.

Пример:
`su user -c "echo $b"`
`123/456/789`

Следует поставить дополнительные экраны:

```
b=${a////\\\\/}
```

т.е. в данном случае мы ставим экран на каждый из экранов и теперь команда
`su user -c "echo $b"`
вернет: `123\/456\/789`

но теперь если выполнить команду
`su user -c "ssh user@hostname echo $b"`
экраны снова выполнят свое предназначение, экранируя символы и исчезают
Для того, что бы экраны передались и в этой команде, мы снова экранируем каждый из них дополнительно:

```
b=${a////\\\\\\\\/}
```

И теперь выводом
`su user -c "ssh user@hostname echo $b"`
будет: `123\/456\/789`